# QT SetItem oworks only in 0x0 field. Why?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

```
while(true)
{
   newItem->setText("wwwwww");

   ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, i, newItem);
   ui->tableWidget->update();
   i++;
}
```

But in table only at 0x0 position I see text. Why?

Comment: Sorry for bad format.

Thank you, fritzone.

Comment: Hi, did you initialize your width/height or your tableWidget with `setRowCount(10);` and `setColumnCount(x);`

Comment: Can you edit your post, putting enough code to reproduce the problem please ?

Comment: I solved it accidentally. the point is I have only one Item. Once I set it, table own it and that's it.